# Psychologist researching rumours with team in isolated base

Tags: story-identification

I think this might have been in an anthology from the 70s.

A small group of colonists live inside a base somewhere in the solar system. They've been there for several months or years. The narrator, some kind of psychologist, is in control of all information from Earth, and doles it out sparingly. The rest of the team, which includes his own wife, is deeply suspicious of him because of this.

They're right to be: the whole thing is his experiment into how rumours develop in the absence of real information. At first, the rumours approximated the real news fairly closely; as time went on, they got wilder and wilder. But the psychologist expected that the rumours would close back to the real news eventually; to his surprise this doesn't seem to have happened. There's a chart showing the line tailing off with a question mark.

In the end he realizes that this is because the others simply aren't telling him what they believe. And when they eventually do come to him, it's to tell him they are leaving; they've come to believe that the whole thing is a sham and the base is on Earth, so they're going to open the airlock and walk out. He tries to persuade them otherwise, demonstrating that they're in lower gravity by dropping a folder on the floor: the others don't think it's falling slowly.

As they leave he tells them: "A madman thinks he's the only one sane", to which one replies "If you like". The story ends with him on his own in the base, and the reader not knowing who was correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Real Time World](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?44500) by Christopher Priest. I read it in New Writings in SF 19.

The psychologist is Winter (I don't think we every discover his first name). The scene at the end is when Winter is talking to Jensen:

> Jenson came back to my office about an hour later.
> “Are you going to come, Winter?” he said.
> I shook my head. “You don’t know what you are doing. You’re going to step out of that tunnel into the moon’s vacuum. You’ll die instantly.”
> “You’re wrong,” he said. “About this and other things. You say we’ve been conditioned—well we’ll accept that. But what about you? How can you tell that everything you think about the observatory is accurate?”
> “But I know,” I said.
> “And a madman knows he is the only one sane.”

At the end Winter is left alone in the base:

> I have been right through the observatory and I have confirmed that I am alone. It is very quiet in here. I sit at my desk, holding a part of my 84 file. Every now and again I hold it out from the desk and watch it fall slowly to the floor.
> Its movement is gentle and very graceful. I could watch it for hours.